# Adding a tableview into a detailsview in Xcode4 causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview, detailsview

I'm working on an UISplitView component for Xcode learning purposes

My application has a list of brands in the popover.  Once an item is selected, the brand's picture, and some details of the brand will be loaded into outlets in the detailview. All was working perfectly until I decided to add a tableview to the detailview of the splitview. The project now crashes on startup!

The project file can be found [here](http://bimsolutions.biz/files/testingsplitview.zip)

I must have misslinked something. Your expert help is much appreciated. The project is done in Xcode 4.

Comment: It didn't crash for me.  What errors are you getting when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run your project without any hiccups. I am not sure whether it did what you intended but it didn't crash. So I think you should try `Product` > `Clean` to clean the project and then build it again to see if it works.

As a side note, you are leaking in this statement - `self.brandProducts =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. You can make that `self.brandProducts = [NSMutableArray array];`. Additionally, you should make your string properties a `copy` property rather than `retain`.

Comment: well weirdly enough, it works without crashing.. 
although, the tableview is not visible.. also thanks for the leaking tip, i will take it into consideration in future coding... but i tried altering many of the codes when i was trying to find where is the crash source! i guess it's something that cleaned when the laptop was shut down! any hints on how to link the tableview in the detailsview to any controller?

Comment: nope, i didn't clean the build.. i just opened my macbook, read ur post, and tried the project and it works.. without cleaning (but i cleaned it anyways) hehe

Comment: any hints about how to make the tableview visible?